# How to automatically merge cells in Google Sheets upon creation of new Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to figure out a way to make Google Sheets automatically merge Cells A1-C1 when a new sheet is created. My coworker and I have been trying to figure out the script that would make this happen, but everything we have tried only changes the previous Sheet we were working on, not the new one.

So far these are the two scripts we have tried, just to get some sort of result we are looking for:

```
 function formatCells() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ();
 var s = ss.getSheetByName('Combined')
 var range = s.getDataRange()

     var values = range.getValues();
  
     for( var row = values.length -1; row >= 0; --row)
       if (values[row][1] == 'Hello')
       {s.getRange(row+1,1).mergeAcross();
    }
  
   }
```

**and**

```
    function newSheetTrigger() {
     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
     ScriptApp.newTrigger('newSheet')
     .forSpreadsheet(ss)
     .onChange()
     .create();
   }

   function newSheet(e){
     if (e.changeType == 'INSERT_GRID') {
       SpreadsheetApp.flush();
       SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A1:C1').merge();
   }
   }
```

Does anyone have an idea of where we went wrong?

Comment: Do you mean, when a new sheet is created by any user? There's no trigger for that. I'd recommend you write the function for the active sheet and let each user decide whether they wish to run it or not.

Comment: Merging cells is a very bad idea and will lead to unexpected problems.

Answer (score 1):

### The problem is that the`onChange` trigger is not able to detect the active sheet correctly

Retrieving the active sheet on trigger will always return you the first sheet, as you can easily verify with

```
function myFunction(e) {
  Logger.log(e.changeType);
  if(e.changeType=="INSERT_GRID"){
    Logger.log(SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet().getName());
  } 
}
```

**So you need to implement a  workaround.**

For example:

- Strore the present sheet names in [Script properties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties)
- When the trigger fires and the condition `e.changeType=="INSERT_GRID"` is fullfilled:
  Compare the currently present sheet number to the one stored in script properties to evaluate either a new sheet has been inserted
- If the sheet number increased - find the name of the new sheet with [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)
- Merge cells on the new sheet and update the script properties

Code snippet:

```js
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

//run me once
function firstSetUp(){
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  var names = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++){
    names.push(sheets[i].getName())
  }
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("sheets", JSON.stringify(names) );
}
//run me on trigger
function newSheet(e) {
  if(e.changeType=="INSERT_GRID"){
    var newSheets = ss.getSheets();
    var oldSheetNames = JSON.parse(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("sheets"));
    Logger.log(oldSheetNames);
    var length = oldSheetNames.length;
    Logger.log("length : " + length);
    if (length != newSheets.length){   
      for (var i = 0; i < newSheets.length; i++){
        if(oldSheetNames.indexOf(newSheets[i].getName()) == -1){
          var newSheet = newSheets[i];
          Logger.log(newSheet.getName());
          newSheet.getRange('A1:C1').merge();
          oldSheetNames.push(newSheet.getName());
          PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("sheets", JSON.stringify(oldSheetNames)); 
          break;
        }
      }    
    }
  }
}
```